# No space on the boot disk to update kernel

Tags: centos, disk-usage

I have installed centos 7 on vmware and seem to have ran out of space on the boot drive.

Is there a way to add more space without formatting the disk?

```
[root@centos7 /]# df -h /dev/sda1
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1       297M  272M   26M  92% /boot
```

Comment: Technically, you can add kernel in any partition and update the grub configuration files accordingly

Comment: I am actually trying to update the system via yum and new update for kernel is available. Would it be possible to add more space to exising /dev/sda1 ?

This would also help me utilize space going forth

Comment: Please share us the content of `du -sh /boot/*`, normal it takes 150MB Max.

Comment: well, `resize2fs` is a command to extend the size of a partition. but it will do when some conditions met. RTFM of resize2fs

Comment: @AngRed Would this suffice ?

`[root@centos7 /]# du -h /boot
4.0K /boot/grub
0 /boot/grub2/themes/system
0 /boot/grub2/themes
2.4M /boot/grub2/i386-pc
3.3M /boot/grub2/locale
2.5M /boot/grub2/fonts
8.1M /boot/grub2
256M /boot`

Comment: Just give it a try, I am not sure if it works. `mv /boot/grub2 /backuip/grub2` and link this to /boot/. So that /boot/grub2 is a link, be carefull with the permission & the owner ship.

Comment: If you have some older kernel packages try to remove that.

Comment: Trying the above suggestions

Answer (score 0):

Below file consume more space on your system (/boot). if you can remove the older file you can free up some space. Make sure you have a backup before attempting remove.

> initramfs-2.6.32-358.el6.x86_64.img
>   System.map-2.6.32-358.el6.x86_64
>   vmlinuz-2.6.32-358.el6.x86_64

Comment: Running `package-cleanup --oldkernels --count=2` would remove all but the running kernel and the most recent kernel.

Answer (score 0):

boot your vm with a linux livecd like Ubuntu Mate or something. once booted use gparted to shrink your / partition and grow /boot to 1G . This will work given the fact that your / has some space left.

Or there is another way.  From VMware documentation here :
http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1004047

For Workstation 7 and later and Player 3.x and later, you can increase the virtual disk from the GUI:
Select the virtual machine from the Inventory.
Click Edit Virtual Machine Settings.
Click Hard Disk.
Click Utilities > Expand, enter the new size, then click Expand.
Complete the steps in Increasing the size of a disk partition (1004071), so that the guest operating system is aware of the change in disk size.

add 1G using above steps. using Gparted move your partitions around and resize /boot .